# Programmatically delete one entry from one field on one entity

Tags: 7, entities

What's the proper way to programmatically delete one specific field entry for a multi-entry field from one specific entity? (that's specific fields and specific entities, not field types or instances and entity types)

Here's some possibilities I've looked into which don't work:

- Loading the entity with `entity_load()`, setting the field entry to =null or =array(), then saving with `field_attach_update()`. It's the closest I've found but it leaves a zombie null field entry in the database which shows up as a blank row on forms until the form is saved and `hook_field_is_empty()` can kick in (`hook_field_is_empty()` is configured such that =null or =array() will flag as empty).
- Loading the entity with `entity_load()`, unsetting the field entry by key, then saving with `field_attach_update()`. This seems to do nothing - it seems that Drupal interprets the entry not being there as a sign to not modify it. (strangely I also sometimes get maximum query time expiration timeouts when trying this approach)
- `field_attach_delete()` - this is much too blunt: it kills all fields for the entity
- `field_purge_data()` - better, but still too blunt: it kills all entries of the field, not specific entries

So to clarify, I've got code that finds (and loads) an entity which has a field that has multiple entries, and finds a specific entry on that field that needs to be removed. I want to remove that entry completely, without touching any other entries or any other fields on the entity.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're able to rely on the [entity API module](http://drupal.org/project/entity) you should be able to use code similar to the following:

```
// Load some entity.
$entity = entity_load_single($entity_type, $id);

// Remove the field value.
unset($entity->field_FIELD_NAME[LANGUAGE_NONE][$index]);

// Reset the array to zero-based sequential keys.
$entity->field_FIELD_NAME[LANGUAGE_NONE] = array_values($entity->field_FIELD_NAME[LANGUAGE_NONE]);

// Save the entity.
entity_save($entity_type, $entity);
```

Comment: This worked! Thanks, my zombie problem has now been erradicated. A few notes that might save others time: I needed to update entity api to RC2; since I was using a dynamic field name the unset line needed braces like unset($entity->{$field_name}[LANGUAGE_NONE][$index]); and to avoid a warning I needed to wrap the array_values() in if(!empty(...)){}

Comment: This also works if you just want to clear the entire field, and avoids the dreaded "Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'field_duty_user_target_id' cannot be null"

Comment: Thanks a lot! tried to change field value through node_load, but it didn't work. So changing entity field value like this definitely works!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do this as part of a Drupal8 migration cleanup.

After some experimentation, I found that iterating and then using unset() on the delta could kill it. My example was removing a tag (hence I search for 'target_id', not 'value' as you often would for other fields.

```
/**
 * Removes a term from a field.
 *
 * @return bool
 *   success
 */
private function removeTerm(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $object, \Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface $term, $field_name) {
  // Check if tag value exists already.
  // Remember they may be multiples.
  /** @var @var \Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList $field_values */
  $field_values = $object->get($field_name);
  foreach ($field_values as $delta => $field_value) {
    if ($field_value->getValue()['target_id'] == $term->id()) {
      unset($field_values[$delta]);
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

And afterwards, if success, then `$object->save();`

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8, to delete a field from an entity:

```
$entity = Node::load($nid);
unset($entity->field_name);
```

This will call the magic method __unset() from ContentEntityBase:

```
public function __unset($name) {
    // Unsetting a field means emptying it.
    if ($this->hasField($name)) {
        $this->get($name)->setValue([]);
    }
    // For non-field properties, unset the internal value.
    else {
        unset($this->values[$name]);
    }
}
```

Don't forget that, to persist your changes, you need to call

```
$entity->save();
```

After you've done all your changes.

Answer (score -1):

This is better way:

```
> $user = user_load($user->uid); 
> $user_wrp = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
> $user_wrp->{'field_data_multiple'} = array();
```

Answer (score -2):

the current preferred method would employ the entity_metadata_wrapper

```
$node_wrapped = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', node_load($nid));

unset($node_wrapped->$field_name[$index];
```

this is the best tutorial on the EMW that i've seen http://deeson-online.co.uk/labs/programatically-access-field-data-using-entitymetadatawrapper-drupal

Comment: this didn't work. I even tried it like this with no luck; 
  $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$duty);

  unset( $wrapper->field_duty_user);
  $wrapper->save();
  node_save($duty);

Comment: The correct way would be $node_wrapped->field_name->set(""); then $wrapper->save()