# How to delete data from a field programmatically

Tags: 7, entities

I have a content type called companies
In this cck I have an Image field and user can add more than one image

I want to make a form programmatically that will display all images in a grid and under each image a button to delete it

Is there is a way to delete it from the node (this specific image only or I should make node_load to get all fields and then check for all images and node_save the node again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's already answered [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31794/programmatically-delete-one-entry-from-one-field-on-one-entity). You just need to build an interface to display images in grid format using views and a delete button is just a link where you pass the node id and delta value of field value to delete.

Once you call the link which will be a custom menu path with callback which executes the code shown in above link to delete the delta field value.