# Coding a Load and delete Field Collection with Entity API

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to delete all values of a multivalued field containing a field collection. I want access with [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) wrappers. I use this in a custom rule with hook_rules_action_info()

I'm using drupal 7.39 and field collection modules 7.x-1.0-beta8 and

I'm testing this code but doesn't work for me, this node has 2 values in field_collection

```
$node_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $node);
dpm($facWrapper->field_collection,"Field Collection");
//Prints a EntityListWrapper object
dpm($facWrapper->field_collection->count(),"Field Collection count");
//Prints zero, it should be 2
dpm($facWrapper->field_collection->value(),"Field Collection value");
//Prints array() 0 elements, it should be 2 elements
//And obviously doesn't enter into this foreach, it should enter
foreach ($facWrapper->field_collection as $fc) {
  dpm($fc,"Field collection item");
}
```

The questions are:

- How to load or access to the field_collection in the entity wrapper way ?
- When I have access, How can I delete ? I want to delete the field_collection_item and its reference in the node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look into this links it will give your answers:

[Example: Programmatically create and update field collection with Entity API](https://www.drupal.org/node/1842304)

[How to properly delete a field collection](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/68765/how-to-properly-delete-a-field-collection)

[Delete field content using entity metadata wrapper](http://dropbucket.org/node/1442)