# Programmatically update field collection data in custom entity

Tags: 7, entities

I am in desperate need of help.

I have a custom entity called **Question** which has a bundle called **data**.
Within the data bundle, I have a [collection field](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) called **options** with two subfields called **correct_option** & **misc_option**.

```
-Question
 -Data
  -options
   -correct_options
   -misc_options
```

**I am desperately trying to programmatically write data into those 2 option fields** but the following code is not working:

```
$field_collection_item_value = 1596; // Get field collection item value.

$field_collection_item = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($field_collection_item_value)); // Load that field collection item.

$field_collection_item->save(); // Save field-collection item.
```

The *1569* is the ID of an existing question entity.

Whenever the code is executed I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function save() on array

I would appreciate any help. I'm at a loss and not sure how to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code for update existing field collection data

```
//$item_id load item id from your node
//enter_update_field_mechine_name replace with your field name  
  $field_collection_value = field_collection_item_load($item_id);
  $field_collection_value->enter_update_field_mechine_name['und'][0]['value'] = 'update text here';
  $field_collection_value->save();
```

This code worked for me
Thank you